# Problem accessing jupyter notebook from Docker Toolbox Container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I just set up a Docker Container with the Docker Toolbox and ran jupyter notebook inside the container using

```
docker run --name container -v %somedirectory%:%someotherdir% -d -p 127.0.0.1:8888:8888 quay.io/fenicsproject/stable:2017.2.0 'jupyter-notebook --ip=0.0.0.0'
```

Afterwards I can check the log of the container to see the [URL and token that jupyter notebook created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKVFk.png).

If I now go ahead and copy the link to my browser, it won't be able to connect to localhost. Accessing 127.0.0.1 does not work either.

Since the Docker Toolbox relies on Virtual Box VMs, I also tried to use the IP address of the VM, in this case 192.168.99.100:2376. According to the Kitematic UI, this is the IP:Port combination that is being published by the docker-machine and indeed this does not lead to a generic connection error. Instead the browser's output is:

```
Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
```

I don't really know what to do from this point on. What does this "error" mean? Does it even make sense to use the VM's IP address? And most importlanty: what else can I do in order to finally get access to the jupyter notebook?

PS: I also tried the suggestions made in the threads [Can't access jupyter notebook from docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064541/cant-access-jupyter-notebook-from-docker) and [Access Jupyter notebook running on Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830610/access-jupyter-notebook-running-on-docker-container) and couldn't make any of them work unfortunately.

I hope someone can help, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'd suspect that, in Docker Toolbox, `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:...` will not make the service accessible from the host (for the same reason container processes can't bind to 127.0.0.1).  Does removing this fragment of the command line, and accessing the `docker-machine ip` address and the published port (`http://192.168.99.100:8888`), work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things to make this work:

1. Remove the `127.0.0.1` part of the port mapping; `docker run -p 8888:8888 ...`
2. Connect to the `docker-machine ip` address with the published port; `http://192.168.99.100:8888`.

Docker Toolbox runs Docker in a separate Linux virtual machine.  Any `docker run -p` options will get interpreted from the point of view of that VM.  If you `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:...` then the published port will be bound to the VM's `lo0` localhost interface, so it won't be reachable from outside the VM.

Once you have the port published, you need to connect to that specific port.  Port 2376 is typically the port to reach the Docker daemon inside the VM, with mutual TLS security; you only need this for manual `docker` commands.  To reach services running inside the VM you need to connect to the published port (the first number in the `docker run -p` option).